# Cálculo de quantas vezes preciso enviar uma string

Tags: c#

Eu tenho um serviço que atualiza status de placas controladoras..

Só que ele só me retorna apenas 22 registros por vez. Então preciso pegar o numero de itens que quero atualizar e mandar a quantidade de mensagens necessárias para atualizar todos.

Exemplo: tenho 5 placas. Mando apenas uma requisição de atualização.
         tenho 23 placas. Devo mandar duas requisições (1 até 22, e a outra só com o 23)

Alguém poderia me ajudar a fazer isso?

Comment: tenta explicar um pouco melhor sua pergunta, por favor mostre seu código c# nos de mais detalhes.

Comment: Talvez seja interessante depois dar uma olhadinha neste tópico para nos ajudar a entender melhor as suas perguntas futuras: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @RafaelSpessotto Não agradeça a respostas com outras respostas. Simplesmente comente, quando tiver a reputação necessária pra isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi bem a pergunta, mas talvez seja algo assim:

```
int numPlacas = CountPlacas();
const int numMaxRegistrosPorMensagem = 22;

int numMensagensNecessarias = (int)numPlacas  / numMaxRegistrosPorMensagem;

if((numPlacas % numMaxRegistrosPorMensagem) > 0)
    numMensagensNecessarias++;
```

Comment: As mensagens adicionais só vão conter uma placa cada? Se sim, está correto...

Comment: Bem observado @mutlei. Já modifiquei o código.